# Is it safe to use an empty binding in IIS?

Tags: iis, bindings

I want to show a specific page for *unbound HTTPS URLs*.
I have set up a basic website with an empty HTTPS binding, and this seems to work ok.

Am I right in thinking it is acting as a 'catch-all' for any HTTPS URLs that aren't already bound to other sites?
Is there a chance it may 'catch' valid URLs that *are* in a binding?

In what order does IIS match a URL against bindings?

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Binding Diagnostics reports how site bindings can be interpreted, which might help you understand the scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct, an empty host name for an https binding catches all requests not already handled by other sites on the server. The IP addresses still play a role as well, if you have multiple ones.

IIS matches more specific bindings first, so one with no host name will be very low in the order.

Any requests to that site will most likely result in a certificate error and the requested host name and the name in the certificate for the site will most likely be different.

I am running catch-all sites on my IIS servers for over ten years and never seen and problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing that should be mentioned is website vulnerability scanning tools may flag those applications as being susceptible to [Host Header attacks](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/07-Input_Validation_Testing/17-Testing_for_Host_Header_Injection) because they reply with a 200 instead of an error, like 404. An example test request would be:

```
curl https://MySubWebsite.MyWebsite.com -H "Host: evil.com"
```

To block the vulnerability, you could set up a very general [Wildcard Host Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support) like `*.mywebsite.com` to catch "valid" traffic and let the rest go to "404".